# Paypal NVP API - SetExpressCheckout, GetExpressCheckoutDetails & DoExpressCheckoutPayment

Tags: asp.net, paypal

I want to integrate Paypal express checkout into my own eCommerce website and for that I am thinking to use `SetExpressCheckout`, `GetExpressCheckoutDetails` and `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` API methods.

But I am not sure whether I can use my PERSONAL (not Business/Merchant) paypal account to accept payment using Express Checkout from website or not.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to use a Premiere or Business account.  You would not be able to use a personal account.